# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kafka.coordinator.group.GroupMetadataManager\$OffsetsMessageFormatter

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am running kafka consumer in windows and getting below ClassNotFoundException while reading from __consumer_offsets topic.

```
kafka\bin\windows>kafka-console-consumer.bat   --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic __consumer_offsets --from-beginning --consumer-property "exclude.internal.topics":"false" --formatter "kafka.coordinator.group.GroupMetadataManager\$OffsetsMessageFormatter"
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kafka.coordinator.group.GroupMetadataManager\$OffsetsMessageFormatter
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
        at kafka.tools.ConsoleConsumer$ConsumerConfig.<init>(ConsoleConsumer.scala:297)
        at kafka.tools.ConsoleConsumer$.main(ConsoleConsumer.scala:52)
        at kafka.tools.ConsoleConsumer.main(ConsoleConsumer.scala)
```

Comment: "kafka.coordinator.group.GroupMetadataManager$OffsetsMessageFormatter" on windows

Comment: Please mark K.Nicholas' answer as correct